# mac mini late 2009 30 s boot delay for grub

Tags: system-installation, boot

on a Mac Mini late 2009 with a SSD I have installed eOS 7. After solving the problem with WLAN and installing some software I was able to work fine. I could not install the grafic-driver from Nvidia because it is no longer supported by kernel 6.2.

But the boot delay problem I still have and can't solve it. The SSD is recognized as bootdevice and is in the list of all bootdevices with the ALT key. I put the grub software in "verbose" mode and see that after about 30 seconds the grub software does its output.

What does the efi firmware from Apple during this time? How can I reduce this delay time to 0?

With efibootmgr I saw no possibility to act on it. Maybe something is hiding for me there.

This is my first time in this forum.

I would be very grateful for your hints and possible help.

With kind regards, willi
Asuncion, Paraguay